# Error with Argument passing to dataflow job fro rest api - cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

can anybody share the the dataflow python code to accept the parameters? I am facing the same issue with the argument passing through rest API. my df code is below:-

```
def run(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Specifically we have the input file in CSV format to read and the output BQ table to write.
    # This is the final stage of the pipeline, where we define the destination

    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        dest='input',
        required=False,
        help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or '
        'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        # This example file contains a total of only 10 lines.
        # Useful for developing on a small set of data.
        default='gs://intient_output/measurementunit.csv')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        dest='output',
        required=False,
        help='Output file to be written. This can be a local file or '
        'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        default='mygcpdataengineerlab:intientpoc.measurementunit'
        )

    # Parse arguments from the command line.
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()
    project = ''

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
```

Exception stack trace below

```
Error-    response = request.execute()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/mygcpdataengineerlab/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Fgcp_dataflow_csv_bq_code%2Ftemplates&alt=json returned "(9744cfd1809f74a): The workflow could not be created. Causes: (9744cfd1809fa2d): Found unexpected parameters: ['input' (perhaps you meant 'update'), 'output' (perhaps you meant 'job_port')]">
```

Comment: Make sure that you are passing --input and --output to the right program. This error is happening because you must be passing --input and --output to the Dataflow service somehow. Dataflow itself does not recognize --input and --output, only the custom parser in your Python script recognizes those options.If you still have trouble, you can provide more information about how you are running your job.

Comment: I am running the code through the cloud function as below:-

Comment: template_body = {
        "jobName": job,
 "parameters": {
            "input": "gs://input/abc.csv",
            "output": "project:dataset.table",   
        },
        "environment": {
            "tempLocation": "gs://gcp_dataflow_csv_bq_code/temp",
            }
    }
    request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=gcp_project, gcsPath=template_path, body=template_body)
    response = request.execute()
 when i remove the parameter option the df is being triggered with the default option

Comment: i also created a _metadata file {
  "description": "Dataflow job template to load data from csv to BQ",
  "name": "parameters",
  "parameters": [
      "name": "input",
      "name": "output",
  ]
} as per the link https://harness.io/2019/10/a-serverless-architecture-to-run-google-dataflow-pipelines/

Comment: I see. The difference between your code and the example you provided is that you use argparse directly, while the example correctly uses Beam's argument parser. You will need to create a subclass of Beam's PipelineOptions that defines your custom parameters, like UserOptions in their example.

Comment: Thanks, got it resolved passing as user options.

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved by accepting the arg as pipeline options.
class MyPipeOpt(PipelineOptions):
        @classmethod
        def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
            parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input',
            help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or a file in a Google Storage Bucket.')

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(argv)
my_options = pipeline_options.view_as(MyPipeOpt)

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
 and used the variables as my_options.input in the beam pipeline created.

Thanks,

Comment: would you mind adding format and showing where you place the snippet described please

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with `dest=input` as this keyword argument is not supported in the latest beam options.
To keep it simple you can do something like this:

```
def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
  """Build and run the pipeline."""
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--output_topic', required=True,
      help=('Output PubSub topic of the form '
            '"projects/<PROJECT>/topics/<TOPIC>".'))

  parser.add_argument(
      '--input_topic',
      help=('Input PubSub topic of the form '
            '"projects/<PROJECT>/topics/<TOPIC>".'))

  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
```

Comment: Like --input and --output in OP's code, --output_topic and --input_topic are locally-defined arguments that are not recognized by Beam/Dataflow.